# proper dataset format to use for object detection with retinanet code example from site keras.io

Tags: python, object-detection, retinanet

I'm trying to use object detection with retinanet code example from keras.io on my own dataset, but i cant find out the proper data format. the code itself is trained on some TFrecord data and i cant find what the format of my dataset should be.

I checked the code functions to find out the proper data format, and i came up with a dictionary data sample as you see it in this image:

[image: my own dictionary data and its format]

but i keep receiving the below error:

[image: the error i receive]

could anyone please help.

Comment: here is the source code: https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Do not post screenshot of your code, add the code and the result to the question itself.